Image mask blur processing problem using ffmpeg
I want to apply blur using masking to two or more points in the image. I want to use a circular or other type of blur in ffmpeg rather than a box blur. I wrote the ffmpeg code, but an error continued. When there is only one blur, it works correctly, but when there are two or more blurs, an error occurs. No matter how much I search, I can't figure it out, so I'd like to ask for help.
The ffmpeg code I wrote is as follows.
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i mask.png -filter_complex "`
[1:v]scale=200:200,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/1:(oh-ih)/1[pmask1]; `
[1:v]scale=200:200,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/3:(oh-ih)/3[pmask2]; `
[0:v][pmask1]alphamerge,avgblur=10[alf];[0:v][alf]overlay[temp1]; `
[temp1][pmask2]alphamerge,avgblur=10[alf2];[temp1][alf2]overlay[v] `
"-map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart maskedblur.mp4

The error is as follows.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000026ed1d4a500] Invalid stream specifier: temp1.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[fc#0 @ 0000026ed1cdc280] Stream specifier 'temp1' in filtergraph description
[1:v]scale=200:200,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/1:(oh-ih)/1[pmask1];
[1:v]scale=200:200,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/3:(oh-ih)/3[pmask2];
[0:v][pmask1]alphamerge,avgblur=10[alf];[0:v][alf]overlay[temp1];
[temp1][pmask2]alphamerge,avgblur=10[alf2];[temp1][alf2]overlay[v]
 matches no streams.
Error initializing complex filters: Invalid argument

